# Polynoms with positive coefficients in R[X]

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

I have difficulty to prove the following assertion:

1) If $P$ is a polynomial in $\mathbb{R}[x]$ with all coefficients $\geq 0$,a then there exist $A,B,C,D \in \mathbb{R}[x]$ such that $P = A^2 + B^2 + x(C^2 + D^2)$.

I could prove the following similar assertion:

2) If $P \in \mathbb{R}[x]$ is such that for all $x \in R$, $P(x) \geq 0$, then there exist $A,B \in \mathbb{R}[x]$ such that $P = A^2 + B^2$

But I am blocked on (1). Thanks a lot for support!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1):

Hint : $P$ is the sum of an even polynomial and an odd polynomial :

$$
\begin{align}
P(x)&=a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+\dotsb \\
&=(a_0+a_2x^2+\dotsb)+(a_1x+a_3x^3+\dotsb).
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Each polynomial can be writen like this: $$p(x) =q(x)+xr(x)$$ where $q(x) = (p(x)+p(-x))/2$ (we get $q$ so that we take from $p$ only the terms of the form $a_{2k}x^{2k}$) and $r(x) = (p(x)-q(x))/2$ 
(so we get $r$ if we divide with $x$ the part of $p$ with all odd degree terms). Now since $q(x)\geq 0$ for all $x$ so all real zeros are even. So $$q(x) = s(x)k(x)$$ where $s(x)$ is greatest polynomial with all real roots of $q(x)$ which divides $q(x)$ and $k(x) = q(x)/s(x)$. So all the zeroes of $k(x)$ are complex and $k(x)$ has real coefficients and $s(x)$ is square of some real polynomial, so $s(x)= l(x)^2$. Since all non real zeroes of real polynomial are in conjugate pairs we can write $$k(x) = (x-a_1)(x-\overline{a_1})(x-a_2)(x-\overline{a_2})... $$
Let $$E(x) = (x-a_1)(x-a_2) ... \;\;\;\;{\rm and}\;\;\;\; F(x)= (x-\overline{a_1})(x-\overline{a_2})...$$
So for real $x$ we have $$F(x) = \overline{E(x)}\;\;\;\;\Longrightarrow \;\;\;\;k(x) = E(x)\overline{E(x)} = G(x)^2+H(x)^2$$ 
where $E(x) = G(x)+iH(x)$ and $G,H$ are real polynomial. 
So $$k(x) = l(x)^2(G(x)^2+H(x)^2) = a(x)^2+b(x)^2$$ if we say $a(x)=l(x)G(x)$ and $b(x)= l(x)H(x)$.

We do similary for $r(x)$ and we are done.